# Get a new list from a given index in Python

Tags: python, list

Hello I currently have the following list

```
df['Longitud_min']
```

0     116.452963
1     116.451522
2     116.449915
3     116.444459
4     116.444383
5     116.444806
6     116.446015
7     116.446925
8     116.447970
9     116.450055
10    116.450395
11    116.454651
12    116.454718
13    116.454453
14    116.449710

I need to get another new list but that starts from item number 1. that is filled in successively

I've been trying to go through the list and assign it but it keeps filling up from the beginning

```
Longitud_max = []
Longitud_max.insert(0, df['Longitud_min'][1])
for i in df['Longitud_min']:
Longitud_max.append(i)

Longitud_max.pop()
```

This is the output of the new list I have added the first index manually but when dynamically filling it it does it from index 0 and I want it to be from index 2

```
df['Longitud_max']
```

0     116.452963
1     116.451522
2     116.449915
3     116.444459
4     116.444383
5     116.444806
6     116.446015
7     116.446925
8     116.447970
9     116.450055
10    116.450395
11    116.454651
12    116.454718
13    116.454453
14    116.449710

Comment: For a typical Python list, you can use [slicing](https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/), for example `mylist[1:]`

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code example,  also show the list contents as proper python types,  is  `1  116.451522` a tuple?  these details will make it easier to understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above normal list slicing works on DataFrames and Series.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Values": range(3)})
>>> print(df)                           # Full dataframe
   Values
0       0
1       1
2       2
>>> print(df[1:])                       # Sliced dataframe
   Values
1       1
2       2
>>> print(df["Values"][1:].to_list())   # Extract series and slice (showing as a list)
[1, 2]
```